# How do I get decimals in C++ if I'm using integer variables

Tags: c++

Here's my code:

```
class Division{
public:
    void div(){
    //This is what to use inside the main
    //Division Divide;
    //Divide.div();
    int x;
    int y;
    int div;
    cout << "Still in Alpha So it only rounds the Number\n";
    cout << "Enter Your Number\n";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Divided by\n";
    cin >> y;
    cout <<  "=";
    div = x/y;
    cout <<  div;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't if you define them as `int`. Try with `double` or `float` instead.

```
double x;
double y;
double div;
```

Changing the definition solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are dividing two `int`'s, so you will invoke integer division, which truncates all decimals. You can change your `int` to `double` and you will keep the decimals.

For example

```
1 / 2      // results in 0

1.0 / 2.0  // results in 0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

[Cyber's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27273497/4320030) answer is correct that you are doing **integer division**. If you want x and y to be integers (to keep the input sane), only div has to be double:

```
double div;
div = static_cast<double>(x)/y;
```

output: `1.67`

The static_cast will **ensure** float division, but you get the benefit of keeping x and y ints.

But you still won't see two decimal places by default when you output it. Use std::fixed and std::setprecision(2) to limit the output.

Comment: He hasn't asked for 2 decimals.

Comment: @Eduardo My answer is still correct, I was merely making a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `int` definitions with `double`:

`double x;
double y;
double div;`